# Outlook APIs OR Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook - Getting meeting room/location in C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, office365api

I am developing a c# windows application, and trying to get availability of meeting rooms/locations using either Outlook APIs or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application object where it will show the available rooms for a given start/end date time.

Appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Recipient.FreeBusy` or `AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy`to get available time of a room in Exchange.